# How do I tell tail -f it has finished - cleanly?

Tags: bash, unix, cygwin, gzip, tail

I am copying a LOGFILE to a remote server as it is being created.

```
tail -f LOGILE | gzip -c >> /faraway/log.gz
```

However, when the original LOGFILE is closed, and moved to a storage directory, my tail -f seems to get some odd data.

How can I ensure that tail -f stops cleanly and that the compressed file /faraway/log.gz is a true copy of LOGFILE?

EDIT 1

I did a bit more digging.

/faraway/log.gz terminated badly - halfway through a FIX message. This must be because I ctrlCed the whole piped command above.

IF ignore this last line, then the original LOGFILE and log.gz match EXACTLY! That's for a 40G file transmitted across the atlantic.

I am pretty impressed by that as it does exactly what I want. Does any reader think I was just "lucky" in this case - is this likely NOT to work in future?

Now, I just need to get a clean close of gzip. Perhaps sending a kill -9 to the tail PID as suggested below may do allow GZIP to finish its compression properly.

Comment: Can you define "strange data" for this case? Also how is the LOGFILE "closed"? `tail -f` is going to keep reading from the file even if you `mv` it. You need to give `tail` some reason to stop following the file.

Comment: If you want a full and complete copy of a file, `tail -f` is the wrong tool for the job, all-stop. Unless you guarantee that it's empty when you start the process, you're not even _likely_ to catch the beginning -- and unless your implementation of `gunzip` is built with the expectation of having compression stream restarts, you're going to get surprises there too.

Comment: @EtanReisner There appears tobe one or two lines missing. I kill the process with ctrl-c as soon as LOGFILE was moved. I need to send tail -f a signal to say LOGFILE is finished - let gzip closeup.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - it appears to work ALMOST... everything was fine until I killed tail.

Comment: @ManInMoon, it only appears to work ALMOST because you haven't tested the other corner cases either. Built-to-purpose tools for remote logging exist. Use them.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy What would you recommend instead?

Comment: Depends. What's the program generating the log? Does it support any remote logging libraries? (If it's written in Python or Java, the answer is certainly "yes").

Comment: Actually, the general-purpose tooling I recommend is logstash: http://logstash.net/. Mind you, that's a much heavier-weight tool than what you're asking for here -- it actually parses your logs into structured data and indexes them for searching with a nice GUI in front -- but if you're serious about making your logs useful, it's the right tool for the job.

Comment: It's quickfix/n fix engine. I just need to mirror this updating very large logfile to a remote machine - that can start processing the copy BEFORE logfile has been fully created. I process the logfile in very specific way - not just a bit of monitoring.

Comment: Take a look at logstash; you don't *have* to use the indexing and parsing and whatnot modules; it's perfectly possible just to use it to incrementally ship your logs from point A to point B (with incremental restart support and all that other good stuff).

Comment: I'd recommend http://www.rsyslog.com/ - light, many sources, easy config.

Comment: @kAlmAcetA All I need to do is copy this logfile as it is created to my local machine. Do you think a product like rsyslog might be overkill? I just need file copied!

Comment: You have couple options - deal with tail or get the right tool (like logstash, rsyslog,...). And it's quite simple - just answer: how important is that?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Can you expand on your compression stream restarts comment a little? I didn't follow that.

Comment: @EtanReisner, note the use of `>>` in a stream with previously-gzip'd content.

Comment: @ManInMoon, ...the other question is how important it is that you gzip your contents while transferring them. If you drop the gzip, you can use rsync to do an incremental pass at the end and get a strong guarantee of correctness.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ah. I see what you meant. Thanks.

Comment: That said -- if you didn't use ctrl+c, and instead did a `kill` on just the tail, that would allow the `gzip` to finish cleanly. Wouldn't fix any of the other problematic cases, but if you're satisfied to not worry about bugs that aren't immediately in front of your nose...

Comment: Ya.  However, the timing to `kill` the `tail` is important.  You have no way to know when exactly `tail` got all the contents.  You may estimate that perhaps 5 seconds after the file is already been deleted, `tail` should have already got all the contents.  However, actual time for tail to finish depends on CPU/memory/IO loads.  For that I mean, we don't know when the last log goes in, when the log file is moved/deleted, and when you `kill` the `tail`.

Comment: @RobinHsu The good thing about usign tail approach is that I am copying the file to my local machine, and I have some c# there that is reading that file and sits waiting for it to be finished BEFORE it carries on with its processing. If I copy the file with something like rSync in differential mode, the c# on my local machine would getting problems when the logfile is update by rsync. Tail allows file to grow. Perhaps there is another utility that does similar?

Comment: If you have control of all the programs that modify/access/delete the file, I believe `tail` can server your purpose.  Your description is clearer but more clarification is needed.  Perhaps you can state your goal similar to this:  Program A @ machine A writes to logfile X, Program B @ machine A reads the logfile X, etc.. And in what sequence will they write/read/delete/move, where that `tail` command fits in, in the sequence, as well as in which program... (like `tail` is in program B @ host B) ... etc..   Instead of saying "I am copying...", I prefer "Program A is copying ..."

Comment: @ManInMoon, yes, you were lucky -- but the ways in which you were lucky had nothing to do with the file size or the distance, and everything to do with the order of operations. You're lucky that both source and destination files were 0-byte when tail first read from it, and that no restart occurred anywhere in the process. If you had *guarantees* about any of those things, you should have posed them as part of your question.

Comment: @ManInMoon, ...indeed, as I implied in my earlier comments (see chatter w/ EtanReisner), the use of `>>` rather than `>` increases the amount of order sensitivity, _implies_ that you expect to be able to restart or append, and thus increases the amount of luck (or planning on factors you didn't specify controlling) involved.

Comment: Ya. but a few adjustment will make it always lucky.  If `tail` would use with `-n +1` option, the tail could have started from sometime where source was not empty (more than 0 byte). The destination, can always starts from 0 byte, by redirecting gzip output to a file by `>` rather than `>>` i.e. `| gzip -c - > somefile.gz`

Answer (score 0):

To get a full copy, use

```
tail -n +1 -f your file
```

If your don't use `-n +1` option, you only get the tail part of the file.

Yet this does not solve the deleted/moved file problem..  In fact, the deleting/moving file problem is an IPC (inter-process communication) problem, or an inter-process co-operation problem.  If you don't have the correct behavior model of the other process(es), you can't resolve the problem.

For example, if the other program COPY the log file to somewhere else, and then delete the current one, and the program then log outputs to that new log file... Apparently your tail can not read those outputs.

A related feature of unix (and unix-like system) worth of mentioning:

> When a file is opened for read by process A, but is then deleted by
>   process B, the physical contents will not be immediately deleted,
>   since its reference count is not zero (someone is still using it, i.e.
>   process A).  Process A can still access the file, until it closes the
>   file.   Moving file is another question:  If Process B, say, moves
>   file to the same physical file system (Note: you may have many
>   physical file system attached on your system), process A can still
>   access the file, even the file is growing.  This kind of moving is
>   just to change name (path name + file name), nothing more. The
>   identity of the file (a.k.a. "i-node" in unix) does not change.    Yet
>   if the file is moved to another physical file system, local or remote,
>   it is as if the file is copied and then removed.  So the remove rule
>   mentioned can be applied.

The missing lines problem you mentioned is interesting, and may need more analysis on the behavior of the programs/processes which generate and move/delete the log file.

**--update--**

Happy to see you got some progress. Like I said, a process like `tail` can still access data after
the file is deleted, in a unix-like system.

You can use 
      ( echo $BASHPID > /tmp/PID_tail; exec tail -n + 1 -f yourLogFile ) | gzip -c - > yourZipFile.gz

to gzip your log file, and kill the `tail` program by

```
kill -TERM `cat /tmp/PID_tail`
```

The `gzip` should finish by itself without error.  Even if you are worried about that `gzip` will receive a broken
pipe signal, you can use this alternative way to prevent from the broken pipe:

```
 (  ( echo $BASHPID > /tmp/PID_tail; exec tail -n + 1 -f yourLogFile ) ; true ) | gzip -c - > yourZipFile.gz
```

The broken pipe is protected by a `true`, which prints nothing, but ends itself.

Comment: Assuming that you are using bash, to obtain the PID of tail to be killed (send signals), use `( echo $BASHPID > /tmp/PID_tail; tail -n + 1 -f your file ) | gzip ...`

Comment: (referring to the above comment): that would certainly work if you ran `exec tail -n +1`; otherwise, you're depending on an optimization that may or may not be present. (Do you know which version of bash automatically `exec`ing the last component of a subshell was added in?)

Comment: (referring to the above comment): not quite sure what you mean... `(echo $BASHPID > ...; tail ... ) | gzip ... &` will certainly forks two processes, one for each side around `|`.  Inside the subshell, `(... ; ... )` the `;` will certainly mean the two parts be executed in the same sub-shell, since it has to be executed in sequence.

Comment: yes, but you don't want the pid of the shell that's parent to the tail but the pid of the tail itself, no? If you run `tail` instead of `exec tail`, then you're potentially getting the parent to the `tail`, unless your version of bash automatically makes the last process an `exec`.

Comment: Ya. You are right. I re-post to correct my comment here: Assuming that you are using bash, to obtain the PID of tail to be killed (send signals), use `( echo $BASHPID > /tmp/PID_tail; exec tail -n + 1 -f yourfile ) | gzip ...`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy & RobinHsu. Please see edited question. I will test whether killing tail allows a clean finish

Comment: Kill -TERM (15) or -KILL (9) does not matter in this case.

Comment: ...but the default of TERM is far better practice in general, absent a specific and compelling reason not to allow a process to clean up after itself.

Comment: I agree the TERM is a better practice.  Yet in some cases, or, to make sure absolutely to terminate a process, KILL signal should be used. (For some very serious script).

Answer (score 0):

From the [`tail` manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html): **Emphasis mine**

> With --follow (-f), tail defaults to following the file
> descriptor, which means that even if a tail'ed file is renamed,
> tail will continue to track its end.  This default behavior is
> not desirable when you really want to track the actual name of
> the file, not the file descriptor (e.g., log rotation).  **Use
> --follow=name in that case**.  That causes tail to track the named
> file in a way that accommodates renaming, removal and creation.

Therefore the solution to the problem you proposed is to use:

```
tail --follow=name LOGILE | gzip -c >> /faraway/log.gz
```

This way, when the file is deleted, `tail` stops reading it.